# Angular – best practice of sharing common code between projects

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to share code between projects ?

I have two apps created using:

`ng generate application app1`

`ng generate application app2`

I want `projects/app1/src/app.module.ts` to import a module from `projects/app2/src/shared/common.module.ts`

What is the best practice for this without creating a 3rd project called common or something ? Create a projects/common or just have a folder called `common` and plate TypeScript files here and import them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use library projects!

```
ng generate library common
```

This will automatically add path aliases to the main `tsconfig.json`

```
  "common": [
    "dist/prod/common"
  ],
  "common/*": [
    "dist/prod/common/*"
  ]
```

Which will allow you to refer to the modules and exported components, services and pipes defined in the `common` library project.

For example in any of your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { SharedModule } from 'common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

An alternative to support hot-reloading during `ng serve` of a consuming app (say, for development) is to import from the common `public_api` from the project level, as follows:

```
import { SharedModule } from 'projects/common/src/public_api';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Give it a try, I've used it heavily and it works marvels! I strongly recommend you read [Angular Docs - Creating libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

Comment: Only caveat with that is you much build your library before using. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: @bhantol - It's a matter of perspective. If by "before using" you mean during `ng serve`, you can always import from the `public_api` ES module. I have updated my answer. But think twice when you say it's a caveat, because at runtime, in production, each one of your apps will have its own separate build bundle anyways. You really need a library to share and distribute this common code.

Comment: I am aware of library and have converted a bunch of projects to library + demo format and makes sense for library projects but overkill to share code, polyfillls, styles. I am unable to parse from your answer which approach is best and why. There is too much noise about "how" than "why".

Comment: i tried it and it works with some additional work also with ngbuild. I think it's ok for ng serve and sporadical build during development, _until shard components are unot finalized_. When a nd just when they will likely never be touched again, you can make a true library of them. That way you does'nt need to rebuild the library every component's change

Comment: Do you think that would be useful to use typescript import aliases to switch easily from  'projects/common/src/public_api to 'common'? (In my case I don't export a single angular module but many typescript classes from public_api, so I need to change that import in a lot of files).

Comment: Great answer. Also, [this](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/08/22/kraken-angular-workspace-multi-application-project/) helped me very much.

Answer (score 5):

If the majority of Apps share the common code, I will suggest another approach using dynamic routing and lazy-loading modules. 
Within the same code base, you can add all App specific code into a new Module.
Then you add a additional flag in the environment file, and create a new environment file, so the App can be built into different bundle by the internment configuration --c.
for more details, have a look this [article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/a-white-label-solution-using-powerful-features-in-angular-7-517444f6fc9)