# Separate Angular apps for customers and staff

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I don't want the angular app used by customers to include everything used by staff:

- It would be much bigger - the staff-related code is 10x larger than that for customers
- It's a security risk - I don't want customers to infer what my system does behind the scenes (I want to protect my IP)

So I probably need two apps - one for customers, and one for staff. Maybe a third for shared code. Is this the correct approach?

If so, the advise I've found is to "eject" and tweak webpack. *But the latest angular doesn't allow this.*

So for the latest angular, how do I setup two related apps in the same project, with a third shared lib?

---

*UPDATE* to avoid the arguments in the comments below

I want a single git repo, which I work on in vscode. Inside I have two angular apps (one for customers and one for staff) and a third app/project/package/whatever for shared code.

Just restricting access to staff-related endpoints is nonsensical - although the customer can't access staff-related features because he is not a member of staff, *he can still INFER my system's features because he can see the code that supports it*. Thus the need for separate apps.

My question was how to do that with the latest angular, because all resources are for older versions.

Comment: I'll give you 2 other options: The first option is to add roles management to your server side and in the front end use those roles to in order to view or hide content.
The 2nd option which is more safe, is to use a reverse proxy like nginx to serve those 2 different applications.

Comment: You can use a single application and use protections to not let your customers access the staff part. That would include role-based authentication, interceptors, tokens ... But Angular is made for that, so I don't see why you should have multiple applications. That seems a terrible idea to me.

Comment: @trichetriche That's not what I meant - it's not that I'm afraid that they can access my staff-related endpoints, because there are logins/roles for that to prevent them from doing do. BUT. The app itself contains code that can access those things. They can figure out my IP by investigating the app's code. Why bundle sensitive IP if they don't need it?

Comment: @Rotemya Your second options is good, but I need to figure out how to structure the apps during development... The serving part is easy enough.

Comment: If you need to structure your app in very standardized way I can recommend you this tool: https://nx.dev/. I'm using it in quite big application and it seems to scale and work out of the box.

Comment: @DariuszOstolski Thanks Dariusz, I'll look into it! Does it cover my use case?

Comment: I think that you should consider carefully before structure your app according to some requirements that might changed. Put all the feature in its own modules (probably all of them are protected) and serve them according to role and token. Open your architecture as much as possible for changes. Leave the logic of "show what to who" to the roles management.

Comment: @Rotemya But if I understand you correctly, that means the app will include code that can access staff features - the user won't be able to because he is not staff, but the code includes it, and he can reverse-engineer and inspect it. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Please remember Two things: 
1. Your code is probably minified. 
2. If the hacker still succeed to reverse it - with basic role based authentication at the server side  the hacker can't do anything with your frontend code.

Comment: @Rotemya Yes that's a good point, it is minified. But that isn't a good reason to serve code full of company IP to customers. Besides, it's dead code, it can't be used by customers anyway, so it just bloats the app.

Comment: The data comes from the server side. This is the place where you should put the auth logic. The frontend just show/hide features but is not responsible for the auth management.

Comment: @Rotemya I realise that, but that still isn't the point. The point is that the client app will contain code that the user can inspect to INFER what the system can do. Via inspecting unminifiable strings, names of endpoints, config values, etc. The app is packed full of IP. You don't want your competitors to see any of that.

Comment: @lonix they don't need to "investigate your app code" to know your IP, simply open the network tap of the dev tools and you'll see it. The security should rely on the server, not the front-end : you should only accept a single origin for your requests, which would then avoid accessing your app from outside. Then, the role based endpoints should take care of what the clients can and can't see. The front-end is supposed to be "dumb" in the sense that it only takes care of itself, and it doesn't try to restrict users from the endpoints.

Comment: @trichetriche So an endpoint called `/api/v1/useSecretFroopleAlgorithmNoOneElseUses` can't be accessed by customers, but now they know that your business is able to use the "Froople" algorithm that no one is yet using. Silly example, but shows that your app leaks IP to your competitors - they will be able to infer the abilities of your system. This is not a tech problem, it's a business problem.

Comment: Yeah well if you explain your algorithms and your frameworks in your URLs, that's on you. Either you're doing that and that's terrible practice, or you're displaying bad faith and simply don't want help, but confirmation that YOUR idea is the right one. In both cases, it seems you don't want to listen to people helping you, and your issue is "resolved", so good luck with your project, see you around !

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you for your advice. Though I was not acting in bad faith - I asked a simple question, and I got two good simple answers, one which I accepted. You were trying to convince me that my question was silly because good auth is enough. But in an IP conscious environment that is poor design. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ionix It should cover your case, what I think you could to is to generate one app for customer one app for staff and put common code in libraries. More accurate link: https://nrwl.io/nx/guide-nx-workspace

Comment: @lonix what I meant by that is that [you didn't ask help for the issue you face, but on the solution you think is the good one](http://xyproblem.info/). I didn't say your question is silly, what I'm saying and was saying is that you don't ask the correct question, resulting in an answer that is a bad practice. But if it suits you, I'm fine with it !

Comment: @trichetriche Let us agree to disagree. Thank you for caring enough about some random internet guy's problems for trying to help, even though we ended up disagreeing. Appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update for Angular v11 and higher :

#### Angular only approach

You can create a new workspace with separated projects inside

```
ng new appName --create-application=false
```

or

```
ng new appName --no-create-application
```

then inside of the created workspace you can create multiple new application using

```
ng generate application my-first-app
```

You can read more about this in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects)

#### Nx approach

Nx is a powerful open-source build system that provides tools and techniques for enhancing developer productivity, optimizing CI performance, and maintaining code quality. Learn more about how Nx works.

You can use Nx to quickly scaffold a new standalone project or even an entire monorepo. It can be incrementally adopted and will grow with your project as it scales.

Nx allows you to create monorepo with application using not just Angular. It also allows you do use microfrontends.

You can create nx workspace using:

```
npx create-nx-workspace
```

But there are a lot of features and techniques so I would recommend to read their [Intro](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro) and decide what type of workspace you want.

To check what frameworks/libraries are natively supported check [packages](https://nx.dev/packages)

There are also community managed [plugins](https://nx.dev/plugins/registry)

It's also possible to add Nx to existing Angular project or even merge multiple existing projects to one monorepo [more here](https://nx.dev/recipes/adopting-nx-angular)

### Original answer (works until Angular v10):

You can create a new workspace with separated projects inside

```
ng new appName --createApplication=false
```

This command will create empty workspace. Then you can create two separated apps and share code between them.

```
ng g application customersApp
```

and

```
ng g application staffApp
```

Now you will have `projects` folder in your workspace and you can run the applications separately.

```
ng serve customersApp --port 4200
```

or

```
ng serve staffApp --port 4201
```

You can put the shared code into angular library

```
ng g library sharedCode
```

It will add path to `tsconfig.json`
Then you will be able to use modules and other exported stuff in your apps

You can also check: [Angular – best practice of sharing common code between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253440/angular-6-best-practice-of-sharing-common-code-between-projects)

The shared code is there explained well.

Comment: THANKS! This is what I needed to know! So the compiler would reference the shared code in each case, and tree-shake the stuff that isn't needed - i.e. the customer app will only include the customer+shared code, and the staff app would only include the staff+shared code?

Comment: Updated the answer with possible solution for shared code.

Comment: At least in Angular 16 on Windows, ```--createApplication=false``` throws an error ```Error: Unknown argument: createApplication```. ```--create-application=false``` works.

Comment: @Chris In Angular 16 it's "--create-application=false" or just "--no-create-application". This answer was written for angular 7. Nowadays there are more options, for example [nx](https://nx.dev). I will update the answer with more details later today.

Comment: I have updated the answer with details I provided in the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend this approach. It's always good to have either 2 separate apps, or as @trichetriche recommended, use permissions.

However, if you insist on building two 'sub-applications' within the same Angular app, you'll have to follow these steps:

- You'll need to include both your apps in your `.angular-cli.json`, so it would look something like this:

```
"apps": [
    { "name":"app1",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main-resolver.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
       "../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    { "name":"app2",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist2",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main-luxury.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

That way, you've told your CLI that you have 2 separate applications, which can be built/served using the following commands:
`ng serve/build --app app1` and `ng serve/build --app app2`

If you're going to be running them simultaneously, make sure to specify the port numbers, since angular serves applications by default on port 4200

So to serve them, you'll have to
`ng serve --app app1`
`ng serve --app app2 --port 4201`

- Now to structure the code, by default angular is going to give you

  - `app-routing.module.ts`
  - `app.component.scss`
  - `app.component.spec.ts`
  - `app.component.ts`
  - `app.module.ts`
    You'll have to replicate these same classes with `app2` as a prefix. And your routes will go accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm not sure I understand you - I was thinking about two separate apps all along. What I don't understand is how to link them with a shared lib so I can work on all of them within the same project (think vscode workspace + git monorepo) and not duplicate code or tests. Is that what your proposal can achieve?

Comment: This is exactly what it can achieve. I've landed my hands on a similar Angular project where it has an interface for the customers and one for the staff members. The way it was handled is as I've described to you.