# Multi-Domain Angular Application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

We are developing one e-commerce portal in `Angular`, where we have only one application, but using domain splitting concept we want to separate the routes, i.e. say my primary domain is `example.com` and the seller dashboard is `seller.example.com`.

Say my routes are:

1. `/login`
2. `/register`
3. `/profile`
4. `/dashboard`
5. `/products/management`

Now, pointer 1,2 & 3 belongs to the primary domain `example.com` where pointer 4 & 5 belongs to the secondary domain `seller.example.com`.

In Laravel, we achieve this with routes by specifying something like this `route(‘shop.home’[‘subdomain’=>request()->route(‘subdomain’)])` which determines if the `route` is valid based on the definitions else it goes to 404.

I'm wondering if there is any such feature or trick available in `angular universal`?

So far here's my implementation:

```
  //console.log(this.window.location.hostname);
if(this.window){
if(this.window.location.hostname == "seller.example.com") {
  this._router.navigateByUrl("/seller/login")
}
}
```

Is there any better solution, as `window` comes as undefined in most of the cases.

Comment: @Chris It's not a duplicate, you might want to go through the problem statement once again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then my apologies, but you still might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116620/separate-angular-apps-for-customers-and-staff/55116823#55116823). If it doesn't help, let me know and we'll figure something else out.