# Angular material desktop with Ionic mobile app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I have built a desktop web application using Angular and Material, and I now want to add a mobile application, using Ionic.  My thought was to use a workspace, and have 3 projects, Angular/Material, Angular/Ionic, and then a library that holds the common code like services etc.

Projects

- Angular/Material app
- Angular/Ionic app
- Shared Library

The more research I do into how to structure the apps, the more confusing it gets.  I have read about using PWA or using Capacitor, but I'm unsure where to go from here.  Essentially, what I need to know is, if I create the project structure above, would this be a correct approach, and am I missing something from the approach?

Comment: The above structure looks reasonable for a mono repo. A progressive web app gives you most of the advantage of native without the signing issues but at the loss of exposure in the app stores. IMO PWA is a reasonable approach for MVP.

Comment: @E.Maggini, thanks for the feedback.  So, there's nothing else I need to consider, I would just work on each project as a separate application essentially, sharing the common library for anything that overlaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular – best practice of sharing common code between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253440/angular-best-practice-of-sharing-common-code-between-projects)